# Switch from Civil Engineering to experimental Physics?

Tags: graduate-admissions, career-path, undergraduate, physics, changing-fields

A couple of years ago, I grew an interest in natural sciences. I then started some hardcore reading and investigation of many physics disciplines that I wasn't familiar with.

I have 9 years experience in civil and structural engineering, having graduated with a Masters in Construction engineering in 2019 from CNAM-Paris. As you might guess, I have been considering a career change for some time, having become indifferent about this industry. I've studied really hard to try and catch up with undergraduates in physics, and I've been tutoring Physics subjects for IB and A-level students (Honestly, I'm falling for this teaching gig).

I am aware that there is a large amount of Physics pre-requisites involved (topics I haven't covered in engineering, like astrophysics, some quantum mechanics etc...) On the other hand, I am still "functional" :P in most mathematics skills like Multi-variable calculus, linear algebra, some topology, I need to brush up on Tensor calculus though. And I have minor research experience because of my masters' thesis.

Despite my intense curiosity and interest in physics and academia, It seems that I might need to start over with an undergrad in Physics.

Some questions:

1- Is undergrad my only option?
2- If I can leverage my Engineering background, another question arises. What area of physics would my background allow me to pursue?
3- I most likely need some guidance or mentorship, any help?
4- I've been studying in "University Physics with Modern Physics 13th Ed (2012)", the Feynman lectures on physics, and I've been going through the lectures of Leonard Susskind, and lately, I started reading John Townsend's "A Modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics". Could you suggest any other books that might be specifically useful for academia?

PS: My main interests in physics focus on experimental physics. lie I said I am loving my teaching experience and I've seen some programs where students get to work as assistant teachers. Another thing that might be helpful in answering my questions: I'm moving to Canada within the year as a permanent resident.

I am terribly sorry if my questions are too broad, I'm trying to get a better understanding of how to proceed following this path. I hope to find some help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part of experimental physics are you interested in? Since I'm imagining experimental quantum/particle physics which seems quite different to your background in civil/structural engineering. Also which country are you located in (different countries can have different pathways)

Comment: Indeed, it is very much different than my background, I know it's a long road to get there, I just want some advice as to how to proceed. It's not easy to find answers on university websites for such a  specific case.
I'm currently in Hong Kong, but like I said, I will be moving to Canada within the year.

Comment: Have you considered leveraging your masters into a PhD in something like "building particle accelerators"? There's a lot of "big" physics research that requires large-scale construction nowadays, and someone's got to have the knowledge to actually build the things.

Comment: @nick012000 Thanks mate, never thought of this! I'll check it out.